# Convert an ip value which is stored as hex inside a string to be converted into actual string value in C++

Tags: c++, data-conversion

Example :  If IP is stored as hex value in a string its ascii value will be \n\003c\005  which is same as 0x0A036305 in hex or 10.3.99.5 in ip format. So how to convert this to string "10.3.99.5" ?

i.e "0x0A036305" from this i have to get "10.3.99.5"

Comment: How is that in any way similar to 0.0.0.0? That's not a representation I've seen before. An IPv4 address is by definition four bytes, and four bytes only, so precisely eight hex letters. That looks like a lot more.

Comment: This really doesn't look like an IP representation. A "hex" representation of an IPv4 would normally be just 4 bytes, and 0.0.0.0 would be 00:00:00:00 or similar. Where have you got this strange string from?

Comment: I've tried but I cannot understand your representation. Could you try explaining it again, more slowly and with more examples. You are using terms like hex value and ascii value as if it's obvious what they mean.

Comment: My bad. Corrected the example in description.

Comment: @RogerDykes: It seems you do not understand what "hex" means. That is just a representation of binary data. A string hex representation of `0x0A036305` would be `"0x0A036305"`. That's 10 characters. Dotted-decimal is another representation. `"\n\003c\005"` is the raw data mis-interpreted as ASCII. (Which generally doesn't work)

Answer (score 0):

This is, like, really simple.

```
std::string in = "\n\003c\005";
std::string out = std::to_string((int)in[0]) + "." +
     std::to_string((int)in[1]) + "." +
     std::to_string((int)in[2]) + "." +
     std::to_string((int)in[3]);
```

Comment: `std::string` can be constructed with zero byte inside. Still, using `std::string` to represent such data is strange, I guess `std::vector<int>` would be more appropriate.